# How to refactor rails methods/classes using Eclipse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style

I am in a situation where I need to clean code. I have to do followings

- Rename class methods in cotrollers
- Rename classes which are extending from other modules and helpers in the controller
- Move classes into modules and break classes into sub classes
- Rename some models
- Apply formating to the code, e.g. alignment, spacing etc

Is there a way to achieve above using Eclipse ?
If not then is there any open source editors/plugins for rafactoring rails application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you to refactor your code: https://github.com/bpo217/refacto